# Change plotting order of bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, pie-chart, r-factor

I'm preparing an appendix plot for a revised manuscript where I need to give information of the within-year ranges (variability) of several variables between years and sites.

I figured the tidiest way to do this (I have 7 sites, 21 years, and 5 variables...) would be to use a rose plot using `coord_polar`. However, I stumbled upon something that has always frustrated me about ggplot - the default ordering assumptions. While factors are easily reordered based on some value, this seems to only work in a **fixed** fashion: as far as I've understood, the order needs to apply throughout the data frame.

In this plot, the ordering needs to depend on a value which changes between years, and therefore the `colour` and `fill` values need to change in plotting order within the panel.

To demonstrate, I've created a reproducible example coded below (pictured in the way it should not work)[image: example of wrong ordering]

Basically, I always need the Site with the minimum value within a given Year to be plotted first (in the centre), followed outwards by the increase in value of the other sites, in order of the original value (see `order` and `diff` columns of the data frame). In other words, some years Site a will be at the centre, some years Site c will be in the centre, etc.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

```
library('ggplot2')
library('reshape2')
library("plyr")

## reproducible example of problem: create dummy data
madeup <- data.frame(Year = rep(2000:2015, each=20), Site=rep(c("a","b","c","d"), each=5, times=16),
                     var1 = rnorm(n=16*20, mean=20, sd=5), var2= rnorm(n=16*20, mean=50, sd=1))

## create ranges of the data by Year and Site
myRange <- function(dat) {range=max(dat, na.rm=TRUE)-min(dat,na.rm = TRUE)}
vardf <- ddply(madeup, .(Site, Year), summarise, var1=myRange(var1),
               var2=myRange(var2))

varmelt <- melt(vardf, id.vars = c("Site","Year"))
varmelt$Site <- as.character(varmelt$Site) # this to preserve the new order when rbind called
varmelt <- by(varmelt, list(varmelt$Year, varmelt$variable), function(x) {x <- x[order(x$value),]
x$order <- 1:nrow(x)
return(x)})
varmelt <- do.call(rbind, varmelt)

## create difference between these values so that each site gets plotted cumulatively on the rose plot
##  (otherwise areas close to the centre become uninterpretable)
vartest <- by(varmelt, list(varmelt$Year, varmelt$variable), function(x) {
  x$diff <- c(x$value[1], diff(x$value))
  return(x)
})
vartest <- do.call(rbind,vartest)

## plot rose plot to display how ranges in variables vary by year and between sites
## for this test example we'll just take one variable, but the idea is to facet by variable
max1 <- max(vartest$value[vartest$variable=='var1'])
yearlength <- length(2000:2015)
ggplot(vartest[vartest$variable=="var1",], aes(x=factor(Year), y=diff)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0,max1, by=1), size=0.3, col="grey60",lty=3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(1,yearlength,1), size=0.3, col='grey30', lty=2) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=1, size=0.5, aes(col=Site, fill=Site)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  coord_polar() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: This doesn't really address your question regarding plotting order, but for the problem at hand, I would really consider using a different geom, possibly **point**. It seems to me it would be easy to misinterpret your intended plot as having stacked bars rather than sort of.. overplotted ones, leading to confusion.

Comment: Or, if you want to stick with bars, you could use `value` on the y axis,  set position to `identity`, fill to `NA`,and just use color on the bar outlines.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MikkoMarttila! I had tried to read a lot on ```geom_col``` vs ```geom_bar``` but had not simply come across this combo of options to get what I needed - if you know of any resources that would have made this clear, or in general explain these functions and their options in one document, it would be great to know. PS yes I've tried lots of point plotting etc. but to show what I needed, this approach just seemed the best especially as telling apart e.g. point colours for 7 groups is really hard visually, compared to filled areas... I'll see how the coauthors feel!

Comment: To be honest I was a bit surprised, too, that the order of the data mattered. So @EmmaWiik I'm not sure I can recommend any resources for that specific problem! But [R for Data Science by Grolemund and Wickham](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html) is worth checking out, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't use stacked bars (`position = "stack"`, which is the default for `geom_bar`), `ggplot2` will actually [use the order of the rows in your data for the plotting order](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1938). So all you need to do, is use the original values for the y-axis (rather than the cumulatively differenced ones) along with `position = "identity"`, and *order your data from largest to smallest `value` before plotting*:

```r
ordered_data <- vartest[order(-vartest$value), ]

ggplot(ordered_data, aes(factor(Year), value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = Site), position = "identity", width = 1) +
  coord_polar() +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

PS. When generating random data for an example, consider using `set.seed` so that your results can be reproduced exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with a single plot of the largest site, and then layer smaller sites on top like so:

```
a <- ggplot(vartest[vartest$variable=="var1"& vartest$order==4,], aes(x=factor(Year), y=value,group=order)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(0,max1, by=1), size=0.3, col="grey60",lty=3) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=seq(1,yearlength,1), size=0.3, col='grey30', lty=2) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=1, size=0.5, aes(col=Site, fill=Site)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  coord_polar() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

b <- a + geom_bar(data = vartest[vartest$variable=="var1"& vartest$order==3,],
            stat='identity', width=1, size=0.5, aes(x=factor(Year), y=value,col=Site, fill=Site))

c <- b + geom_bar(data = vartest[vartest$variable=="var1"& vartest$order==2,],
            stat='identity', width=1, size=0.5, aes(x=factor(Year), y=value,col=Site, fill=Site))

c + geom_bar(data = vartest[vartest$variable=="var1"& vartest$order==1,],
            stat='identity', width=1, size=0.5, aes(x=factor(Year), y=value,col=Site, fill=Site))
```

This produces the following:
[image: stacked plot]

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was aware of this option but due to the number of variations I had, was trying my best to avoid it!